# Вопрос новичка!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему в этом коде выдает ошибку?

```py
a = int(input('Введите число') 
q = 2 
while q != a: 
    w = 2 
    if w//q == w/q: 
        print(q) 
        q += 1 
    else: 
        w += 1
```

Comment: Текст ошибки - государственная тайна?

Comment: А код у тебя тоже в строчку написан?

Comment: нет, написан в 8 строк с отступами, я здесь писал так же, но выдало все в строку

Comment: Очень информативный заголовок. Он привлечёт к Вашему вопросу очень много желающих ответить. Табличку "sarcasm" доставать надо из широких штанин?

Comment: У есть возможность поправить код кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1019734/edit).

Answer (score 1):

```
q = 2 
a = int(input('Введите число'))

while True:
    w = 2 
    if w//q == w/q: 
        print(q) 
        q += 1 
    else: 
        w += 1
```

Забыл int закрыть

> a = int(input('Введите число')

А если возникают вопросы то пользуйся этим сервисом http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit